# HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections WordPress

Tags: php

SO I am getting this error and searched everywhere for a reason. From what I have read this code should work. It is not using a url to write the file but instead a relative path. All the file permissions are set up right to `755` so dont think that is the issue. I even had a plugin developer looked at it and he didnt see an issue. Anyone got any ideas why this error is happening?

Error:

```
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://************/wp-content/uploads/simpleecommcart/digitalproduct/13-1.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/***********/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-e-commerce-shopping-cart/models/SimpleEcommCartProduct.php on line 880`

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpyv2ztG' to 'http://***********/wp-content/uploads/simpleecommcart/digitalproduct/13-1.jpg' in /home/stagingpeak/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-e-commerce-shopping-cart/models/SimpleEcommCartProduct.php on line 880`
```

The upload code (I wrote 880 where the error was):

```
    //check for product image upload 
    if(strlen($_FILES['product']['tmp_name']['image_upload']) > 2) {
      $dir = SimpleEcommCartSetting::getValue('product_folder');
      if($dir) {
        $filename = preg_replace('/\s/', '_', $_FILES['product']['name']['image_upload']);
        $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
        $src = $_FILES['product']['tmp_name']['image_upload'];
 880-->     if(move_uploaded_file($src, $path)) {
          $_POST['product']['product_image_path'] = $filename;
        }
        else {
          $this->addError('Product Image File Upload', __("Unable to upload file","simpleecommcart"));
          $msg = "Could not upload file from $src to $path\n". print_r($_FILES, true);
          throw new SimpleEcommCartException($msg, 66101);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does `$dir` contain? I think it doesn't contain what you think it does

Comment: `$dir` is grabbing the setting value of the folder to upload in images. (2nd line)

Comment: Yeah, but *what* does it contain?

Comment: just the path `http://************/wp-content/uploads/simpleecommcart/digitalproduct`

Comment: Yeah and how do you suppose you are going to move files over **http**?

Comment: @PeeHaa I looked at that question so are you saying I should just not use the http and just hard code in the relative path based off the location on the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82853/discussion-between-packy-and-peehaa).

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying as well as what is stated in the dupe (one of many). Doesn't WP have some magic constant or global with the correct path?

Comment: Got it working by using the direct path. I would accept your answer if you put one down. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP wrapper doesn't allow writing (for good reason) so this won't work in the way you were hoping, you'll need a stream that allows writing such as:

(Preferably) File: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

FTP: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

Comment: I am a little confused on this, or how to fix it. It was working a few months ago and I dont think anything has changed besides the server I am on (so maybe the PHP version is different?)

Comment: Also isnt  `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product']['tmp_name']['image_upload'], $path))` the correct way anyhow? All that is different is my code is storing `$_FILES['product']['tmp_name']['image_upload']` in the var `$src`